# Eclipse IDE : How to know exact jar file for classes loaded at runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runtime

I have web application that is running in Jboss container.
Sometime I need to debug the code and for the I need to know from which jar current class is being referred (so that i could search of source jar of the corresponding jar)

Is it possible to get this Jar information (name of the jar file) from which current class is being referred. See the attached screen shot - from where i am trying to get this jar file information. Not sure if my approach is right or wrong [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse allows you to make code changes during debug time.

So, if you want to entering in a class and know what is the jar source of this class just do CTRL + Mouse Right click in the class name and you enter inside the class.

If you have the "Link with Editor" option selected in your Package Explorer you can see automaticly what is ths jar file you are importing.

Comment: It's useful for you? If yes, please aproove the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Compile time classpath` settings are different from `Runtime server classpath` settings.

So if you want to know all the locations/jars that contain a particular class at compile time in eclipse then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the class name. If there are multiple `jar` files with same `class/namespace`, then the order will be defined in `Build Path settings --> Order and Export`.

Runtime reference depends on class loading policy of your server configuration. But usually first it refers from local project, then manifest and then from common class path library.

If your server is configured to refer the `workspace` location of your project, then most probably the order would be as you defined in `.classpath` file, and you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to find it out.

### Edit

It seems you want `eclipse` to resolve the source file automatically. If you are using `maven` then run below commands to refresh the `source` and `javadoc` for all your jar files.

```
mvn dependency:sources
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```